# Import only auth and firestore from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to reduce the firebase library size in my vuejs app. I currently import firebase as

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Inside my vendor file I have the database and messaging services but I have no use for them. [image]

How do I go about only importing auth and firestore into firebase object?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First you need to import the core

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

then import required modules

```
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

or

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to include these as separate dependencies in package.json?

Comment: with code splitting you can reduce 400k on the first run

Comment: That's what I'm hoping. It's my biggest dependency by far.

Comment: where do you consume what is imported by 'firebase/auth'? Why not just import firebase.auth?

Comment: You can also `import { auth } from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/auth';` on files you need firebase auth. Same for `firestore` and other modules. Only import the modules you use in each file.