# Importing only auth package from firebase module

Tags: firebase, webpack

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718421/import-only-auth-and-firestore-from-firebase?rq=1) highlights how you should import distinct firebase functionality into your web app.

In my VueJS SPA, I want to only include firebase/auth into my web app. According to the thread, the following snippet is all that is required.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Unfortunately, the answers/comments in that thread do not specify where exactly this import needs to go and don't explain any part of the snippet either.

I tried adding the above code in my main.js file (the entry point of my app and also where I initialise firebase); however, the entirety of firebase is still bundled into my app after altering my import statements accordingly (as shown below).

[image]

**My question is, where else do I need to include the above snippet in my web app? Do I need to include *both* import lines every time I import firebase into a Vue component that uses firebase functions?**

Additionally, I feel like my question stems from a lack of understanding of what's actually happening with the imports. **Why do we have to `import * as firebase` and then `import 'firebase/auth'`?**

This [Medium post](https://medium.com/@zwacky/using-firebase-you-might-be-able-to-save-220kb-744269f845cc) also demonstrates importing specific firebase packages and references 'tree-shaking' but doesn't explain much further. Reading the docs on ['tree-shaking'](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) helped me understand the concept but not how it works in relation to the firebase example.

**Note, I'm currently using Webpack v3.6.0 as my bundler.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 2023 Update

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

import {
  GetAuth,
} from "firebase/auth";

import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getFirestore,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export { auth, db, collection, doc, getDoc }
```

## Previous Answer

`firebase/app` is the core firebase client. Everything else is optional services.

By using `import firebase from "firebase/app"` You get the core functionality that firebase provides, that means you may not need to use `firebase/auth`, `firebase/firestore`, `firebase/functions` and only use the services that your app requires, reducing the amount of code needed for your app to run.

There are a number of ways to import firebase. However, In all of my projects I have a separate firebase file that I import when ever I require to use any firebase service.

Example

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/messaging";
import "firebase/database";

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: ""
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
firestore.enablePersistence({ experimentalTabSynchronization: true });


export { firebase };
```

And use the following to import

`import { firebase } from "path/to/file"`

## Update

> experimentalTabSynchronization has been deprecated use `synchronizeTabs` instead.

> The `timestampsInSnapshots` setting now defaults to true and you no
> longer need to explicitly set it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So to clarify, if I were to have a similar setup and I just wanted `firebase/auth`, I would just remove all the import statements from line 3 - 7 as well as the firestore stuff at the bottom right?

Comment: "experimentaltabSynchronization" has been renamed to "synchronizeTabs" and "timestampsInSnapschots" is now true by default and therefore does not need to be explicitly set. Both settings ("experimental...." & "timestampsin...") will be removed in a future release.